# should gui be visible during unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, user-interface

I am unit testing my application with JUnit. It uses (or tries to use...) the MVP pattern, hibernate and a swing gui.

In my test, I am testing whether persistence works as expected, e.g. is the date format correct, are the relationships between the database tables correct, etc.

Here's an (edited) example:

```
@Test
public void testCheckBeitragCalculation() {
    MainView view = new MainView();
    view.initGUI();

    Controller persist = new Controller(view);
    persist .saveData(testObject);

    Controller edit = new Controller(view);

    Controller search = new Controller(edit);

    search.getData("10001"); // primary key

    TestObject t2 = edit.getViewData();

    assertEquals(10, t2.getBeitrag());
}
```

I initiate the main view because two controllers needs a reference to the main view to pass data.

Controller `persist` persists the object, Controller `edit` is the controller for the editing view and Controller `search` needs a reference to `edit` because it looks up an entity in the database and then displays this data in the editing view through the `edit` controller.

Because these controllers display the data in the GUI, the GUI shows up a split second during the unit test.

Is that bad practice? I've read that you shouldn't test GUI code, but I'm not testing the GUI itself, it just gets called by the tested code.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: If you ever run those tests on a machine with no display (buildservers on Linux...) you'd be in trouble. You might want to check out mocking frameworks like mockito to hide your UI when testing controller/model

Comment: No no no no. No. A Unit test must test a UNIT, not the entire application. Also, if you're passing your MainView (which is a Class, not an Interface!) into the Controller, those two are coupled too tightly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer to this. In general if it solves your purpose then you can go ahead with this but again if in future your product build system adds these junit test cases to execute after each build through scheduled daily build (e.g. jenkins) and the box where build runs (generally some server) doesn't support any UI (or it is not available at that particular time) like XWindows then your test might fail.